# Error decrypting password: (87, 'CryptUnprotectData', 'The parameter is incorrect.')

Tags: python, botnet

hi i am getting an error with CryptUnprotectData and when i run the command line I get Error decrypting password: (87, 'CryptUnprotectData', 'The parameter is incorrect.') please help me update the source code and get it working correctly

I don't know what to do please help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.